# Get Relations of a Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, foreign-keys

I want to get relations (or foreign keys) of a Sql Server `Table` in my c# code.
How can i do this?
Thank you

Comment: follow this link [how-to-get-the-table-a-foreign-key-refers-to][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458913/how-to-get-the-table-a-foreign-key-refers-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get all the foreign keys that `dbo.YourTableName` references:

```sql
SELECT 
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(pt.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_col = pc.name, 
    Referenced_col = rc.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS pt
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON pt.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND pt.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON pt.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND pt.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
WHERE pt.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableName');
```

If you want to get all the foreign keys that reference `dbo.YourTableName`, it's only slightly different:

```sql
SELECT 
    -- add these two columns:
    [Schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(pt.parent_object_id),
    [Table] = OBJECT_NAME(pt.parent_object_id),
    FK = OBJECT_NAME(pt.constraint_object_id),
    Referencing_col = pc.name, 
    Referenced_col = rc.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS pt
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
ON pt.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
AND pt.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
ON pt.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
AND pt.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
WHERE pt.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableName');
---------^^^^^^^^^^ change this
```

You can put this in a stored procedure, parameterize the two-part name you pass into the `OBJECT_ID` function, and then call the stored procedure from your C# code.