# Get Reference of ForeignKey by SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, smo

I want to gather information about an specific table, So this is my Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine();
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "";//MyConnection string
Server srv = new Server(conn);
Database db = srv.Databases["MyDataBase"];
Table tb = db.Tables["MyTable"];
foreach(Column c in tb.Columns) {

   sb.AppendLine(c.Name + " -> " + c.DataType.ToString());
   sb.AppendLine(c.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString());

  if(c.IsForeignKey){

    //Need to get reference here:
    //Sb.AppendLine("ReferenceColumn")
    //Sb.AppendLine("ReferenceTable")
    //Sb.AppendLine("ReferenceSchema")
  }
}
```

I find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458913/how-to-get-the-table-a-foreign-key-refers-to) but this link get `Foreignkeys` at first, is there any way to find reference here (mean by `Column` type)? What is your suggestion in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for!

```
foreach (ForeignKey FKey in currentTable.ForeignKeys)
{
    foreach (ForeignKeyColumn FKColumn in FKey.Columns)
    {
        //Hope this is what you are looking for!
        //Check the output of FKColumn.Name
        //Check the output of FKey.ReferencedTable
    }
}
```